# SwiftUI: Make Circle "fit" the Text element

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EntryHeaderIconView: View {
    private let backgroundSize: Double = 88
    private let color: Color
    private let initials: String

    init(color: Color,
         initials: String = "") {
        self.color = color
        self.initials = initials
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Circle()
//                .frame(width: backgroundSize,
//                       height: backgroundSize)
            // Uncommenting this fixes the issue, but the text now clips
                .foregroundColor(color)
            icon
        }
    }


    @ViewBuilder
    private var icon: some View {
        Text(verbatim: initials)
            .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("entry_header_initials")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .red,
                                initials: "RT")

            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .green,
                                initials: "LV")

            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .red,
                                initials: "中国")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the `Circle` element to fit perfectly around the `Text` element. However, it either continues growing in the `VStack`, so that it occupies as much space as possible and looks like this (sizing lines commented out):

[image: commented out]

Or, if I set a fixed size to the `Circle`, the content gets clipped:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: backgroundSize,
                       height: backgroundSize)
            // Uncommenting this fixes the issue, but the text now clips
                .foregroundColor(color)
            icon
        }
    }
```

[image: clipped]

My goal is to make the `Circle` size dependent on the `Text` size, so that it grows (or shrinks) together with it.

Pretty easy to make with AutoLayout, how to achieve the same with SwiftUI?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60343575/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to post this as it is a different take on the other two answers, which are simpler and do work. This is a bit more flexible in handling different sizes, but still making them look consistent. This uses a PreferenceKey to read the size of the initials and restrict the circle to a certain size as a result.

```
struct EntryHeaderIconView: View {
    @State var textViewSize = CGFloat.zero
    // This gives a consistent additional size of the circle around the intitials
    let circleSizeMultiplier = 1.5
    // To give it a minimum size, just have the size introduced here
    let minimumSize: CGfloat

    var backgroundSize: CGFloat {
        min(textViewSize * circleSizeMultiplier, minimumSize)
    }

    private let color: Color
    private let initials: String

    init(color: Color,
         initials: String = "") {
        self.color = color
        self.initials = initials
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Circle()
                // The frame is sized at the circleSizeMultiplier times the
                // largest dimension of the initials.
                .frame(width: backgroundSize
                       height: backgroundSize)
                .foregroundColor(color)
            icon
                // This reads the size of the initials
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(
                        key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                        value: geometry.size
                    )
                })
        }
        // this sets backgroundSize to be the max value of the width or height
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) {
            textViewSize = max($0.width, $0.height)
        }
    }


    @ViewBuilder
    private var icon: some View {
        Text(verbatim: initials)
            .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("entry_header_initials")
    }
}
// This is the actual preferenceKey that makes it work.
fileprivate struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Edit:

Unless the icon is a SF Symbol, it will have to be handled differently. However, I have updated the code to add a `minimumSize` constant and changed `backgroundSize` to be a computed variable. This view is not set up to handle an image, but you would simply need to determine how you wanted to constrain the image, or do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946584/7129318).

Comment: It's a good take, but I need to make the circle "at least" of a certain size, if that's possible. Could you please modify your solution to reflect that?

Comment: Do the initials need to change size as well, or is it just that the circle needs to be a certain minimum?

Comment: The initials might change the size based on the accessibility text settings, but the font will always be the same.

Also, I didn't show in this example, but instead of the initials view, an icon might be shown (of a fixed size)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the idea that it scales the background to match the label, that's exactly what I asked for, so that there wouldn't be no case as shown with the Chinese characters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply a padding to the text and then show a background in the shape of a circle.

Here's how you can achieve that:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("1")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(.red)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                Text("2")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(.red)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                Text("3")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(.red)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `ZStack` takes up as much space as its child views need. You aren't providing an explicit `frame` to the `Circle`, so how could SwiftUI know that the `Circle`'s size should match that of the `icon`?

Instead, you should add the `Circle` as a `background` to your `icon`, after applying some `padding` to the `icon`.

```
struct EntryHeaderIconView: View {
    private let color: Color
    private let initials: String

    init(color: Color,
         initials: String = "") {
        self.color = color
        self.initials = initials
    }

    var body: some View {
        icon
            .padding(.all, 30)
            .background(background)
    }

    private var background: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }

    private var icon: some View {
        Text(verbatim: initials)
            .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("entry_header_initials")
    }
}

struct EntryHeaderIconView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .red,
                                initials: "RT")

            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .green,
                                initials: "LV")

            EntryHeaderIconView(color: .red,
                                initials: "中国")
        }
    }
}
```